# Nashorn access non-static Java method

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

In Java 7 (1.7), I could access a Java method from JavaScript by running this:

```
ScriptEngine jse = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jse.eval("importClass(net.apocalypselabs.symat.Functions);");
jse.eval("SyMAT_Functions = new net.apocalypselabs.symat.Functions();");

String input = "notify(\"Foo\");"; // This is user input

jse.eval("with(SyMAT_Functions){ "+input+" }");
```

Which would run the notify() function from the Functions java class:

```
public class Functions {
    private Object someObjectThatCannotBeStatic;
    public void notify(Object message) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString());
    }
    /* Lots more functions in here, several working with the same non-static variable */
}
```

How do I access the Functions class in Java 1.8 with the Nashorn engine?  My goal is to run different code for the first snippet if the user has Java 1.8, while still allowing people with 1.7 to use the app.

I've tried http://www.doublecloud.org/2014/04/java-8-new-features-nashorn-javascript-engine/ , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html , and [How to instantiate a Java class in JavaScript using Nashorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965194/how-to-instantiate-a-java-class-in-javascript-using-nashorn) without luck.  None of them seem to allow me the same thing as Java 1.7 did, instead assuming I only want to access static functions and objects.

The most common error I get:

I start with...

```
ScriptEngine jse = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jse.eval("var SyMAT_Functions;with (new JavaImporter(Packages.net.apocalypselabs.symat)) {"
                    + "SyMAT_Functions = new Functions();}");
```

...then...

```
jse.eval("with(SyMAT_Functions){ "+input+" }");
```

...spits out...

```
TypeError: Cannot apply "with" to non script object in <eval> at line number 1
```

Comment: What's not working in Java 8?  Is there an error message or stack trace you can include?

Comment: @WilliamPrice The errors change depending on the method I try to use.  My problem is I can't access non-static methods in Java 8, no matter how hard I try.

Comment: @WilliamPrice OK, I've edited in one of my attempts and what it got me.  I've tried all the different methods given in those links, if I remember right they all gave me that `TypeError` after tinkering with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to compile and bundle the "old" Rhino interpreter with my application instead of using Nashorn.

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Using+Rhino+JSR-223+engine+with+JDK8

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce.  First of all, Nashorn doesn't try to make it difficult to use Java objects (non-static or otherwise) in general.  I have used it in other projects and not had any major issue converting from Rhino in Java 7 beyond what is covered in the [migration guide](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide).  However, the issue here appears to deal with the use of the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) which is "not recommended" and is even disallowed in `strict` mode of ECMAScript 5.1, both according to MDN.

Meanwhile, I found [a thread on the Nashorn-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2014-July/003178.html) discussing a similar case.  The relevant part of the response was:

> Nashorn allows only script objects (i.e., objects created by a JS 
>   constructor or JS object literal expression) as scope expression for 
>   "with" statement. Arbitrary objects . . . can not be used as 'scope' expression for 
>   'with'.
>
> In jdk9, support has been added to support script objects mirror other 
>   script engines or other globals (which are instances of ScriptObjectMirror).

It's not the most elegant solution but, without using JDK 9, I was able to get your intended use of `with` to function by writing a proxy object *inside the Javascript* to mirror the `public` API of the Java class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.script.*;

public class StackOverflow27120811
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine jse = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        jse.eval(
            "var real = new Packages.com.example.StackOverflow27120811(); " +
            "var proxy = { doSomething: function(str) { return real.doSomething(str); } }; "
        );
        jse.eval("with (proxy) { doSomething(\"hello, world\"); } ");
    }

    public void doSomething(String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

---

[Attila Szegedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131552/attila-szegedi) pointed out the *non-standard* Nashorn [Object.bindProperties](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Object.bindProperties) function.  While it can't be expected to work with anything but the Nashorn engine, it *does* eliminate the complexity of re-declaring all of the public API inside the `proxy` object.  Using this approach, the first `jse.eval(...)` call can be replaced by:

```
jse.eval(
    "var real = new Packages.com.example.StackOverflow27120811(); " +
    "var proxy = { }; " +
    "Object.bindProperties(proxy, real); " // Nashorn-only feature
);
```

Comment: Nashorn also exposes a non-standard function on the `Object` constructor named `bindProperties`. With that, you can add all properties of one object as bound properties to another object; that basically gives you automatic proxying of the kind you did (you can also create composites by binding more than one object's properties, but I digress). You could use `var proxy = Object.bindProperties({}, real);` in your above example. I know, it'd be better if we extended with statement so it can accept a POJO… it's not a hard technical limitation, just something we couldn't get to develop so far.