# Java Nashorn Run Java Function From Javascript

Tags: java, nashorn

I have been using ClearScript for .NET for quite a long time. I have been exposing C# functions and classes to javascript like this: `engine.AddHostObject("ftp", new ftp());`

After that I could do `engine.eval("ftp.upload(""));`

I have been trying to do something similar with nashorn for java but I can't figure it out. What would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nashorn access non-static Java method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120811/nashorn-access-non-static-java-method)

Comment: Please provide the behaviour you observe/error you get.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is the Nashorn equivalent of what you've posted.

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
factory.getBindings().put("ftp", new ftp());
factory.getEngineByName("nashorn").eval("ftp.upload('')");
```

Comment: For adding function I was using this: engine.AddHostObject("save", new Func<string, string, int>(SaveFile));

and adding Class (not instances, so I could use var x = new Html() in JS) I used this: engine.AddHostType("Html", typeof(Html));

Do you know what would be equivalent in Nashorn? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
factory.getBindings().put("ftp", new ftp());
factory.getEngineByName("nashorn").eval("ftp.upload('')");
```